# Requests being doubled if Tomcat is slow to respond

Tags: node.js, apache, tomcat, nginx

We are working with the following stack:

A node express middleware running on Nginx is communicating with an Apache, which proxies the requests to Tomcat, that are located on another server. Now, when requesting an operation that takes more than 15 seconds to complete, another identical request will be sent. There is obviously a 15-second retry policy somewhere.

So far, I have been unable to detect exactly who is doing this and my Google searches have also been fruitless. So, my question is if anyone has experience with something like this and could it be Node, Nginx or Apache that is sending the second request.

Any suggestions on where the double requests are coming from and what property I need to adjust to turn them off would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the socket timeout property in apache's jk_mod to 0.